# How to change to next slide programatically on AppIntro library of paolorotolo?

Tags: android

I have a slide in my app intro which asks for permissions. 
I use the AppIntro library from https://github.com/paolorotolo/AppIntro.

It's not using the permission request functionality from app intro library, but the Dexter libraryinstead. This is working fine, but i want to switch to the next slide of app intro automatically by calling something like .nextSlide on my TutorialActivity (which extends from AppIntro)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i found a way to avoid this situation completely with making the AppIntro "go on" button handling the saving of data.

Answer (score 0):

I used this statement:

```
pager.setCurrentItem(ApplicationState.isRTL() ? pager.getCurrentItem() + 1 : pager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
```

`ApplicationState.isRTL()` is my getter to check application layout is `RTL` or not.

Comment: Which method you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you simply call:

```
pager.goToNextSlide();
```

*But I'am searching for how to go to the last Slide...*
**RESOLVE**

```
while (getPager().getCurrentItem()!=sliderTotalCount)
        pager.goToNextSlide();
```